# MATLAB ignore security certifcates

Tags: matlab, ssl

I need to access some XML from the internet using MATLAB, and to get it I need to download the security certificate from the website manually and use the following function with the downloaded certificate;

```
% Title: inportcert
% Author: MathWorks Support Team
% Code Version: 1.0
% Type: MATLAB soruce code https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/1142/importcert.m
function importcert(filename)
    if (nargin == 0)
        % If no certificate specified show open file dialog to select
        [filename,path] = uigetfile({'*.cer;*.crt','Certificates 
        (*.cer,*.crt)'},'Select Certificate');
        if (filename==0), return, end
            filename = fullfile(path,filename);
    end
    % Determine Java keytool location and cacerts location
    keytool = fullfile(matlabroot,'sys','java','jre',computer('arch'),'jre','bin','keytool');
    cacerts = fullfile(matlabroot,'sys','java','jre',computer('arch'),'jre','lib','security','cacerts');
    % Create backup of cacerts
    if (~exist([cacerts '.org'],'file'))
       % copyfile(cacerts,[cacerts '.org'])
    end
    % Construct and execute keytool
    command = sprintf('"%s" -import -file "%s" -keystore "%s" -storepass 
    changeit -noprompt',keytool,filename,cacerts);
    dos(command);
```

which will allow me to use the following command;

```
xmlread('https://finds.org.uk/database/images/index/format/xml');
```

These certificates expire and I would not be able to manually change the certificates at that point so I was wondering if;

A) Can I automatically download the certificate using MATLAB instead of doing it manually

B) Just ignore the certificate completely, security isn't an issue.

C) Preferably do A or B without the need for Admin rights

NOTE: It seems that you need to go through this process if you're using a Windows-based system, using MacOSX or Linux you will not need to import the certificates and can access the page without getting an SSL Handshake error.